# Dynamic data for JQuery in ASP.NET pages

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Problem**

I have some pages that need dynamic data from website to generate output to users.

A simple solution is an aspx(php, ...) page to generate data and create another html page serving as GUI retrieving data from first page and showing it to users. in this method I can call my GUI page for example form1.aspx and my data page form1.json.aspx.
although I personally like  this method, it is not suitable when creating components for it.

Another method that currently I'm using is using same GUI page call itself with a querystring to retrieve data. this page should check for that query string and if it exists, only generate data and remove everything else from page. As an example for this method if I call my page form1.aspx, to retrieve data, I need to call it like form1.aspx?JSON

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Request.QueryString.ToString().IndexOf("JSON") == 0){
        this.Controls.Clear();
        Response.Clear();
        // send pure data to client
    } else {
      // render page as GUI
    }
}
```

However this method becomes too messy if I add master page and/or inherit my page from some template page. Master pages can only removed in `Page_PreInit` and that adds another extra method.

Security controls cause another problem, if user leaves page open for long time until session expires any attempt to retrieve data will fail cause security module will redirect the request to login page.

Next problem is I cannot consolidate my component in package because it needs modification in page (removing master page, clearing page components ...).

**What I'm looking for:**

1- I'm looking for a solution that I can call my page and get pure data (JSON or XML format) and doing so run a server side method that generates data, so I don't have to worry about what another designer puts in their master page or template.

2- I think it is possible to use `axd` extension to do this but I don't have a clue about it and couldn't find a helping document either.

3- Is there any better way of doing this. any suggestion or solution to improve this much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Page methods. Check this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/2008/09/29/using-jquery-to-call-asp-net-ajax-page-methods.aspx or http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
- WCF JSON service: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON

Other ways of doing is using an HTTP Handler. Implement IHttpHandler interface and register your implementation in your Web.config file. Later call it using jQuery ($.get / $.post):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx

**EDIT**
As OP pointed out, in order to access *session state* in a page method you should use `WebMethodAttribute` this way:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, following your first link take me to [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). Although it is still not usable from inside server controls, your answer is better solution for what I was doing. having separate service, handler or page to retrieve data is out of question because of requirement that says I need to have my methods in same file. the other remaining concern is webmethod is static so I need to check for data security separately from page itself.

Comment: @BobSort I understand what you say about your _requirements_ but I honestly believe you need to re-formulate and re-think your architecture and go for a WCF service or HTTP handler. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: Problem with WCF, HTTP handler and also he static page method is that they don't have access to session and cookies that makes it hard to implement security methods on them. Although I don't like the current architecture, unfortunately I can't change it as I'm middle tier programmer who develops component for programmer and implements architecture's requirements :(

Comment: @BobSort You're wrong now. An HTTP handler has access to HttpContext so you've access to session, cookies...  And about WCF, if you're planning to host WCF services on IIS, and you active ASP.NET compatibility mode (google this!), you've access to HttpContext too... so... what's the problem? ;)

Comment: You are right, I checked again and I noticed I'm doing it wrong. I need to use `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` instead of `[WebMethod]` to access to same session as my page. please include this and the [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) in your answer for others who have the same problem as me and I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use webservice instead of aspx page to return a JSON or XML string and then the caller page (any aspx page) will response after process is success.

So with this webservice, any third party page will have access to your server side method.

To create a webservice pls Check this link: [Create and use Asp.net web service basic](http://gugiaji.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/quickly-mastering-create-and-use-asp-net-web-service-from-basic-database-access-to-ajax-enabled/)

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your response, this falls under 1st method I explained. I like to call same page to get data (call will be redirected to component inside page)